# Get total users for each month doing a group by on month and user_id in mysql

Tags: sql

```
+----------------------------------+
|id |user_id | created_at | status
+----------------------------------+
| 5 | 10    | 2019-08-01 | PAID |
| 6 | 10    | 2019-09-01 | PAID |
| 7 | 10    | 2019-09-01 | PAID |
| 8 | 11    | 2019-08-01 | PAID |
| 9 | 11    | 2019-08-01 | PAID |
|10 | 13    | 2019-09-01 | PAID |
|11 | 15    | 2019-08-01 | PAID |
|12 | 16    | 2019-08-01 | PAID |
|17 | 25    | 2019-09-01 | PAID |
|18 | 25    | 2019-08-01 | PAID |
|28 | 37    | 2019-08-01 | PAID |
|29 | 38    | 2019-09-01 | PAID |
|30 | 37    | 2019-10-01 | PAID |
|31 | 38    | 2019-10-01 | PAID |
+--------------------------------+
```

How to fetch total users for each month doing a group by on created_at and user_id. Ideally if there are user_id's repeating in a month then it should be considered as single user.

So basically the output should be like shown below where its showing `unique` **users** in each **month**

```
count   created_at
---------------------
6       2019-08-01
4       2019-09-01
2       2019-10-01
```

Tried with below query but not able to apply group by on **user_id** 
gives wrong results.

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) as datetime, count(*) FROM payments
where status = 'PAID'
and created_at >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00' and created_at <= '2019-10-30 00:00:00'
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', created_at) order by datetime;
```

Comment: There is no `date_trunc` function in MySQL. Please tag the correct RDBMS that you are using.

Comment: Count distinct users: `count(distinct user_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count unique `user_id` per month, just use `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)`:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) as datetime, 
       count(distinct user_id) as user_count
FROM payments
WHERE status = 'PAID'
      and created_at >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00' 
      and created_at <= '2019-10-30 00:00:00'
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', created_at) 
ORDER BY datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `count(distinct userid)`-

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) as datetime, count(distinct userid) FROM payments
where status = 'PAID'
and created_at >= '2019-08-01 00:00:00' and created_at <= '2019-10-30 00:00:00'
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', created_at) order by datetime
```